# Use Python along with Github API to collect data from a repo

Tags: python, api, github, web-scraping, pygithub

I'm researching on a project, which involves python to use GitHub API to collect the no of stars, contributors, PR's and issues from a repo (https://github.com/ and store it in a CSV file.

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup4, but API method is a more stable way to go.
Below is my small snippet. Im not sure how to get the info of no of issues raised by certain contributors of a company v/s non-company(to check the external contributors) using github API(pygithub).

```
from github import Github
# using username and password
# or using an access token
g = Github("***************************")
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print(repo.name)

print("**********Get Current Repos**********")
user = g.get_user()
user.login
print(user.login)
repo = g.get_repo("<any-repo>/<any-repo>")
repo.name
print(repo.name)
print("********Get the Repo Topics**************")

repo = g.get_repo("<any-repo>/<any-repo>")
repo.get_topics()
print(repo.get_topics())

print("*****Get the Star Count*************")
repo = g.get_repo("<any-repo>/<any-repo>")
repo.stargazers_count
print(repo.stargazers_count)
print("********Get the Open Issues*********")
repo = g.get_repo("<any-repo>/<any-repo>")
open_issues = repo.get_issues(state='open')
for issue in open_issues:
    print(issue)

print("******Get the Branch Count*******")
repo = g.get_repo("<any-repo>/<any-repo>")
print(list(repo.get_branches()))
```

PS: Im still a python noobie.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Currently, Im following a same model as written in https://medium.com/quick-code/python-web-scraping-tutorial-74ace70e01

Comment: Add the code to the post please and explain what is wrong.

Comment: Added a small snippet. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to collect the details of  the projects of `kubevirt` organization?

Comment: I want an in general answer to get Contributors, PR's and Open Issues, and store them in an excel sheet.

Comment: In general , I wanted to know how to extract info about contributors and PR's.